# Any way to anticipate session timeout?

Tags: java, struts, servlet-filters, session-timeout

Is there a way to "catch" the session timeout event, so as to retrieve data from HttpSession before its invalidated ?

We're implementing the Filter Interface, and in the doFilter method, the user we stored in the session object at login is null when session times out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what langauge, what kind of server etc.

I know in ASP.NET you can do a function when the session times out in the global asax

Comment: @Bob: A team member told me that. "In .net, you can..."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to register an [HttpSessionListener](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) for your webapp that will allow you to get notified when a Session is destroyed.

It has two callback methods:

- `public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se)`
- `public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se)`

The `HttpSessionEvent` class has a `getSession` method that should let you get the affected session.

The listener class is registered in the `web.xml`

```
<listener>
  <description>My Session Listener</description>
  <listener-class>
    my.package.MySessionListener
  </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: thanks, but will I be able to do a `session.getAttribute()` inside the sessionDestroyed method?

Comment: The HttpSessionEvent lets you get the HttpSession object, so you should be able to.

Answer (score 0):

Have the user object implement HttpSessionBindingListener, then it can see for itself when it is added to or removed from the session.

Answer (score 0):

You can always ad a piece of JSP that will check to see if your session is still active or valid - basically check to see if a session var exists (!=null) and if it doesn't - redirect the user to another page -

```
<% 
// check for session object
HttpSession validuser = request.getSession(); 
// check to see if session var exists
if (validuser.getValue("auth_user") == null) { 
response.sendRedirect("admin3.jsp?access+denied");
}
// if the session var is null then redirect the user
```

Hope this helps
Mark

Source : http://www.coderanch.com/t/279538/JSP/java/jsp-session-timeout