# Struts2 interceptor to track last page before session timeout

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

I have a web application where if the user session has timedout and they try to login in again i need to redirect them to the last visited page. ONLY for session timeout, if the user logged out i donot want this mapping.

I understand that it can be done using an interceptor and a application scope mapping. But can you give me a code sample for an  interceptor that updates current users url? Also my application scope object..how do i say after say 5 hrs of no relogin remove the reference to last page for that user???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about registering an `HttpSessionListener` (look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3064384/617996)). That way you will be notified when session is destroyed so this is the perfect time when you can save info about last visited page to database.

Your session listener should look like this:

```
package com.rr87;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

public class YourSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
  @Override
  public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    // Implement logic to save last visited page to database...
  } 
  .
  .
  .
}
```

To register your session listener, add code below to your **Web.xml**:

```
<web-app ...>
    <listener>
          <listener-class>com.rr87.YourSessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

And last part of an answer.. You can erase last visited page reference in database on sucesfull logout.

**[EDIT]**

From the official documentation, regarding session object accessible trough `HttpSessionEvent`:

> The container creates a javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent object
>   that is input for calls to HttpSessionListener methods. The
>   HttpSessionEvent class includes the following method, which your
>   listener can call:
>
> HttpSession getSession()
>
> Use this method to retrieve the session object that was created or
>   destroyed, from which you can obtain information as desired. See
>   "Introduction to Servlet Sessions" for information about the
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpSession interface.

Based on that I think, that you can still get data from 'destroyed' session.

Comment: How can i get the last visited page info in my interceptor?

Comment: will request.getRequestURL() give me the current pages url info??

Comment: You understand me wrong.. `YourSessionListener` is not interceptor, it is listener... You should get last visited url inside interceptor or servlet filter that is fired on each request and store it to session to retrieve it inside YourSessionListener.

Comment: so i will have an interceptor that will get the url using  request.getRequestURL() and where will i store this value? it cannot be a session as the sessionListener Destroy method is called after the session is destroyed, Right??... will i just store that in the DB? Can you explain the flow pls...

Comment: Based on comments of this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3064384/617996), I think you can still get  HttpSession object... Correct me please if I am wrong...